# How do I switch between two Observables in order and have the subscription fire twice?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I am using RxJS. I have two Observables (API calls) that return a different amount of information for the same array. I want to switch between the Observables and have the subscription recognize both results, i.e. fire each time a value is returned.

Here's an example using Typescript (this does *not* work):

```js
let foo = [];
const callOne$ = this.service.getSomeData$; // this should take 0.5 seconds
const callTwo$ = this.service.getAllTheData$; // this should take 6 seconds

callOne$.pipe(
    switchMap(data => data.length > 0 ? callTwo$ : of(data)
).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data); // this fires once but I want it to fire twice
    foo = data;
});
```

The above example retrieves `callOne$`, then retrieves `callTwo$`, and then gives me the result. Instead I want the results of both in order. How would I subscribe to the Observables so that the first result is received and then updated by the second call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the best result is to use `concat()`, which responds to Observable results in order.

In other words:

```js
concat(callOne$, callTwo$)
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data); // this will fire twice
    foo = data;
});
```

This code will return two results for `data`, updating the variable in the order of the `concat()` list.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way may be

```
merge(callOne$, callTwo$)
.subscribe(data => { 
    console.log(data); // this fires twice but results are not guaranteed to be ordered
    foo = data;
});
```

You can keep the order but have a single event emitted with something like this

```
forkJoin(callOne$, callTwo$)
.subscribe(([data1, data2]) => { // this fires once with both results ordered
     console.log(data1); 
     console.log(data2);
     foo = data;
 });
```

If you want to have 2 separate notification maintaining the order, i.e. first the result of callOne$ and then the result of callTwo$, you may try to use the `expand` operator like this

```
callOne$.pipe(
  expand(val => callTwo$),
  take(2)  // to make sure you do not call callTwo$ infinitely
)
.subscribe(data => { 
  console.log(data); // this fires twice and the results are guaranteed to be ordered
  foo = data;
});
```

Looking at the fact that `foo` is an array, you may be inclined to the use of `forkJoin`, i.e. the second option.

You may find a more detailed explanation in [this article](https://medium.com/@enrico.piccinin/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).